# How to allow anonymous introspection requests to Queries and Mutations behind Authorize attribute in Hot Chocolate 12?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hotchocolate

Currently I have both my Query class and my Mutation class annotated with a `HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute` and that makes it mandatory to be authorized to get the schema. How do I allow anonymous access to the schema of queries and mutations that require authorization to work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible at this time, but there are supposed to come some changes in 13.0.0 to authorization, so it might be possible then. But can't confirm. I've tried quite a few things personally, and asked in the slack, and couldn't find a way to do it in the current version (12.2.8).